# Convert HTML page along with CSS into PDF using Java or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, headless-browser, html-to-pdf

I am working on converting HTML page into PDF file with multiple pages.

Previously I used PhantomJS. But it reached EOL. I am looking out for changing the PhantomJS library.

I tried example with headless chrome. 
Can anybody give me example for using Firefox, HTMLUnit or SlimerJS.

Answer (score 0):

In *Java* you can use for example [openhtmltopdf](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf).

> Open HTML to PDF is a pure-Java library for rendering arbitrary well-formed XML/XHTML (and even HTML5) using CSS 2.1 for layout and formatting, outputting to PDF or images.

In *JavaScript* you can use for example [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) ([YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WJOfCnoqShw)).

> A library to generate PDFs in client-side JavaScript.